# SwiftUI text field stops the event to fire NavigationLink when .simultaneousGesture attached

Tags: swiftui, navigationlink

I have the following NavigationLink:

```
NavigationLink(destination:
         TrendSlider(
            title: .constant(title),
             col: .constant(self.dataModel.queryColumnSeasonWinPercentageTeam1),
             opIndx: self.$dataModel.seasonWinPercentageTeam1OperatorIndxValue,
             val: self.$dataModel.seasonWinPercentageTeam1SliderValue,
             lBound: .constant(self.dataModel.seasonWinPercentageTeam1Values.first!) ,
             uBound: .constant(self.dataModel.seasonWinPercentageTeam1Values.last!),
             lRange: self.$dataModel.seasonWinPercentageTeam1RangeSliderLowerValue ,
             uRange: self.$dataModel.seasonWinPercentageTeam1RangeSliderUpperValue,
             step: .constant(1.0),
             displayReadableQuery: $readableQuery

   )) {
       HStack {
          if readableQuery.hasSuffix("IS ANY") {
                Text(title)
                Spacer()
                Text("IS ANY").foregroundColor(Color("TPLightGrey"))
            }else{
                Text(readableQuery).foregroundColor(Color("TPOrange"))

            }
       }
   }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
       sendViewSelectionEvent(name: self.title, referral: "Game")

   })
```

If I leave in the ".simultaneousGesture...", then the tap on the Text elements don't trigger the NavigationLink action, however the rest of the row does work.

If I remove .simultaneousGesture, the row can be tapped anywhere again.

Bug?

Answer (score 5):

Adding the `.simultaneousGesture(:)` call is creating a tap gesture recognizer on the label of the `NavigationLink`, not on the row itself. Two facts about gesture recognizers explain the observed behavior.

1. The label of the `NavigationLink` is actually sitting *above* the list/form row (see picture), meaning it will now intercept any taps before they reach the list/form row.
2. Any part of a view with opacity of 0 will not intercept taps, allowing it to pass through to the next gesture recognizer; in this case, the list/form row.

So when you tap on one of the text views, the tap is handled by the `TapGesure.onEnded()` closure. But when you tap on the space in between, the tap "passes through" and gets handled by the recognizer on the list/form row, triggering the `NavigationView` seque.

So, a SwiftUI design decision, and not a bug. Currently, `List`/`Form` is not built to recognize custom gestures while maintaining navigation functionality. If you have a use case for this kind of behavior, [submit some feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com), and maybe we'll see it next year.

[image: View Hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the explanation. It makes sense. And it made me look for a proper way to trigger my call.

```
.onAppear(){ .... }
```

I was trying to emulate a viewWillAppear type event on tap of the navlink. I put the onAppear on the vStack and it works great.